# Label html type not rendering color in android Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When we bind the html text in Label the color is not rendered in android. It showing only black color. But in IOS it's working fine. Code snippet mentioned below,

View Code:

```
<Label Text="{Description}" TextType="Html" />
Description = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(sampleHtmlText);
```

ViewModel:

```
string sampleHtmlText = @"<p><br></p><p><b style=""font-size: 14px; color: rgb(150, 185, 16);"">What does the plan provide?</b></p><p><br></p><p><span style=""font-size: 14px;"">The plan is extremely comprehensive.</span></p></p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android inline CSS style will not been renderer even if we set the **Type** as **Html** . So we could use the plugin [HtmlLabelPlugin](https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin) from Nuget .

Install it in every Xamarin.Forms project(share project and iOS , Android).

**iOS: AppDelegate.cs**

```
HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
```

**Android: MainActivity.cs**

```
HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
```

#### in xaml

```
xmlns:htmlLabel="clr-namespace:LabelHtml.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=HtmlLabel.Forms.Plugin"
<htmlLabel:HtmlLabel x:Name="label"/>
```

```
 string sampleHtmlText = @"<span style='color: green'>What does the plan provide?</span>";

label.Text = sampleHtmlText;
```

Comment: just what i was looking for !!